# HTML5 - Draw on canvas after timeout

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw a line on a canvas after a timeout period. One of the "lineTo" parameters is being sent a value from a variable that is being declared in another script and is being passed as a window.var....

I have a console log set up to execute at the same time as the variable is accessed in the canvas script as well.

onLoad, everything executes as it should. After the timeout, the console shows that the variable has a value, but the canvas line is not drawn.

At first I had no timeout inserted and the variable kept coming back as undefined. I opted to go with a timeout, as I don't fully understand callbacks yet.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script>
   window.setTimeout(render,8500); 

 function render(){   
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var end = window.testVar;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(4, 28);
  context.lineTo(end, 28);
  context.lineWidth = 10;
  context.stroke();

  console.log(end);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Where and how is this variable defined?

Comment: I have a separate script between the <head> tags that fires a function "onload". This function goes out to a server and resolves a small array of datapoints. One of the points is passed on to a window.var. I'm stumped because the value is displayed in the console log, so I know that the variable is defined....just can't figure out why the canvas doesn't take this variable where I have it mapped to one of the lineTo parameters and draws the line.

Comment: Okay, so I replaced the var in "context.lineTo(end, 28);" with a static number "context.lineTo(55, 28);", and the line is not drawn either. So apparently it's nothing to do with the variable at all. The code seems to work when it's not inside of the render() function. Can anyone tell where I'm messing up here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error....

I'm using WYSIWYG Web Builder, and I'm using layers. Some how, the canvas element was marked as "visibility: hidden";

Since the background of the canvas is transparent, I didn't catch it.

To all, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

`context.lineTo` expects a number, so cast your `testVar` to a number

For example:

```
var end = parseInt(window.testVar);
```

Your code above works fine for me...the line draws itself after the specified delay:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

window.testVar=23;

window.setTimeout(render,2000); 



function render(){   
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var end = window.testVar;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(4, 28);
  context.lineTo(end, 28);
  context.lineWidth = 10;
  context.stroke();

  console.log(end);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of casting it in that fashion, so thanks for that bit of information. Unfortunately, I changed the variable to a static integer and the line still failed to draw, so it has to be something in my render function that is causing the problem.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me (see example added to my answer)...at least the part you're showing us.  The problem does not appear to be in the render.